# Spring Boot Admin often reports java.io.IOException (Connection closed prematurely)

Tags: spring-boot-admin

I'm for the moment monitoring 9 Spring Boot applications with Spring Boot Admin server 2.0.3.

8 of those applications are being monitored fine, but there's 1 Spring Boot application that often reports the following error:

```
{
    "statusInfo": {
        "status": "OFFLINE",
        "details": {
            "exception": "java.io.IOException",
            "message": "Connection closed prematurely"
        }
    }
}
```

All of these applications run on AWS, in the same VPC - so I'm doubting this is a general network issue, as the other 8 applications are being monitored correctly.

On the application side, I don't see any failures. So it's very hard to investigate this problem and I'm looking for a solution to get closer to the real problem ...

Anybody with some idea's?